# What are best practices for measuring SEO success using the marketing funnel?

Tags: marketing, goal-tracking, reporting, measure

I am new to corporate marketing measurements but not new to SEO. My company is asking for me to use the marketing funnel - something like http://cdn2.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/KPIs-to-measure-inbound-marketing-effectiveness.jpg.jpg

I am having a hard time translating this into SEO measurements that connect all the way down to the bottom of the funnel, and how to juggle the micro (keyword and page metrics) and macro (overall unpaid site metrics).

For example, I posted a link with optimized anchor text on Reddit (a micro activity). Potential things I could measure include: How much traffic does that sub have, how many people clicked the link (over what time period), etc.

What I'm having issues with is I see it more on a macro level - the potential increase in ranking we could see on a page level or keyword level. I am just confused as to how I can plug in either or both of these metrics, and what metrics to use, to show the impact using the marketing funnel from the top down!

What is best practices for SEO measurement? What are the important metrics to include when analyzing how organic converts to customer acquired? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please ask more specific questions? As it is, this comes dangerously close to being closed for being too broad. I do appreciate your existing questions. As far as I am concerned, you can keep them. I am suggesting a *for example...* to help narrow down the specific problem. Cheers!!

Comment: Absolutely! So sorry. I will emend my question.

Comment: It's okay! I just wanted to make sure you got an answer. Cheers!!